# How I can compare a React Component in different pages using Cypress?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, cypress

I want to compare if a component is the same in another page using Cypress. Example:
I have a **Pricing Component** in *Home*, I want to test if the values in *Pricing Page* is the same.

I tried this, but don't works:

```js
describe('Comparar o componente Pricing em diferentes páginas', () => {

    it('', () => {
        cy.visit('http://localhost:3000')
        cy.get('.package-name').contains('Iniciante').invoke('text').as('name')

        cy.visit('http://localhost:3000/pricing')
        cy.get('.package-name').contains('Iniciante').invoke('text').as('name2')

        expect("@name").to.be.eq("@name2")

    })
    
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The alias you set are not like variables. Use a `.then()` to extract it's value.

You can also set `http://localhost:3000` as `baseUrl` in `cypress.config.js`.

This is how your test would work:

```js
cy.visit('/')
cy.get('.package-name').contains('Iniciante').invoke('text').as('name')

cy.visit('/pricing')
cy.get('.package-name').contains('Iniciante').invoke('text').as('name2')

cy.get('@name').then(name => {
  cy.get('@name2').then(name2 => {
    expect(name).to.be.eq(name2)
  ])
})
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).